# Set global variable as class in the __constructor

Tags: php, class

How can I set the `class DB` as global `$db` in this class as `_constructor`, because I don't want to add in all function the `global $db`.
If I set the `global $db` in all functions it works but in the `__constructor` it doesn't works.

```php
<?php

if(isset($_POST["login_button"]))
    {
            $login = new Login();
            $login->check();
    }

    class Login {
        protected $db;
        function __construct(){
            $this->db = $db;
            global $db;
        }

        function check (){
            $db->query("do something");
        }

        function ban (){
            $db->query("......");
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: You can access it **after** making it global. When it is global, why are you using it as protected property?

Comment: Each method use like - 
            $this->db->query("do something");

Comment: In each method, you just need to use `$this->db`.  Try and *forget* `global` ever existed.

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null in

Comment: Have your db instance be a constructor argument, then use `$this->db`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your use of `global` is a bit off. `global $db` semantically means: `$db` is a variable from the global scope, please use this inside this function's local scope. Therefore, I assume in your code or imports, the $db is initialized with a database object somewhere.

If that's how it is, it would make sense the other way round:

```
        function __construct(){
            global $db; // first, make it locally visible
            $this->db = $db; // remember it for later use in this class
        }
```

But: $db **must** be initialized before creating the class. In your example code, there's no hint on where this is coming from and what exactly it is.

Assuming it already was initialized before creating a Login instance you can then use

```
            $this->db->query("...");
```

in every method. So, no need to write `global $db;` in any other method except the constructor. Instead, use the local copy in `$this->db`.

There isn't a way to enforce a global variable to be available in every local function's scope without using global.

Comment: This might work (and answers the question in the title I guess) but isn't a good idea at all. If said class needs a database instance, it should be injected into it (preferably through a constructor parameter).